# Application WithEvents

Tags: vba, class, excel

I want to control all of my applications events, and found that using `WithEvents` would provide that solution. I read the [Application Events In A Dedicated Class Module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) section of a post by cpearson.

What I'm trying to figure out, is: do you need to have a `ThisWorkbook` event procedure, for each class event procedure you create?

In the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private ExcelEvents As CApplicationEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ExcelEvents = New CApplicationEvents
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set ExcelEvents = New CApplicationEvents
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set ExcelEvents = New CApplicationEvents
End Sub
```

and in the `CApplicationEvents` class module:

```
Private WithEvents appExcel As Application

Private Sub appExcel_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Debug.Print "worked!"
End Sub

Private Sub appExcel_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Debug.Print "calculating... !"
End Sub

Private Sub appExcel_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "workbook name:" & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set appExcel = Application
End Sub
```

I originally thought the `Workbook_Open` procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module would allow creation of any event procedure within the class module, however without creating a corresponding event procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module, the event code in my class module does not trigger and run.

I'm basically after clarification that if I create a new `appExcel_WorkbookBeforeClose` event procedure within my class module, is it then also compulsory to create a `Workbook_BeforeSave` procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module, again declaring `Set ExcelEvents = New CApplicationEvents`? If so, what advantage does using a class module have in this scenario? It seems like duplication of code to me.

Comment: Not sure why, but simply exiting excel and going back in has now resolved the issue. I can now add new event procedures into the class module with only having the `Workbook_Open` event procedure in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: In ThisWorkbook module you should declare ExcelEvents  as Public, not private.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to instantiate again and again  `Set ExcelEvents = New CApplicationEvents`. You only need to create it once and hold a reference on it, in `Workbook_Open`.

As long as you hold a reference on that instance, it will stay alive, BUT if the VBA project **unloads**, either:

- by an explicit `End` statement somewhere in the code (which is unlikely)
- or if the the code breaks during debugging; for example an unhandled error is thrown
- or you stop the execution manually while in the debugger

In these cases, you loose the instance. you can verify it in the immediate window by asking `?ThisWorkbook.ExcelEvents Is Nothing`

When the instance is lost, you don't need to exit and re-open the workbook, you can just just lauch again, manually, the `Workbook_Open` routine (place the cursor inside it and press `F5`). The instance will be created again and you can continue you development session normally.

p.s. The above reasoning actually applies to *all global variables*. Whenever the project unloads for any of the reasons mentioned above, they are reset: Strings to `""`, numbers to `0`, and objects to `Nothing`... But you have the possibility to recreate or re-create them or set them either in the immediate window or by launching any piece of code that does.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean fully, but inside the class appExcel needs to be set to Application.  Like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set c = New cApplication

c.INITIALISE Application

End Sub
```

and in the class

```
Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

    Public Sub INITIALISE(x As Excel.Application)
        Set app = x
    End Sub
```

Hope this helps, i didnt fully understand the post.

THanks

Nathan.

Comment: I have a `Class_Initialize` procedure within my class module, so when the variable `ExcelEvents` is set as an instance of the class in the `ThisWorkbook` module, it automatically initiates the class. I'm more wanting to understand whether I should need to have additional procedures for each event within both the class module and the `ThisWorkbook` module.